# "a" RKHS or "an RKHS"

Tags: article-writing

I am confused if I should use "a" or "an" before RKHS (reproducing kernel Hilbert space). Since "R" is not a vowel, I think I should use "a". But I saw both on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space).

Can you tell me which is correct?

Thanks, 
Pan

Comment: This is more of a question about English, not mathematics. But to help you out, if we voice it "Ar-Kay-Eitsj-Es", it's *an*. If it's "Rakhs" or something similar, it's *a*. The rule is not about how you write it, but rather about pronunciation.

Comment: If you care about things like this, you'll never finish writing. Just don't worry about it; no one cares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read it as an initialism, by saying the names of the letters, it begins with a vowel (sound), and you’d write ***an*** RKHS. If you use it as an abbreviation and actually say the words that it abbreviates, you’d write ***a*** RKHS, because it’s ***a*** reproducing kernel Hilbert space.